# A problem regarding the proof of ${p^nk\choose p^n}\equiv k\mod p$, where $p\nmid k$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In [this proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Coefficient_involving_Power_of_Prime), there is a statement where:

$$(a+b)^{p^nk}\equiv (a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^k\mod p$$ I understand this part. But then it expands both sides binomially, and compares coefficients of $\displaystyle{a^{p^n(k-1)}b^{p^n}}$ to conclude $\displaystyle{{p^nk\choose p^n}}\equiv k\mod p$.

If $k<p$, then none of the coefficients in the binomial expansion of $(a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^k$ are divisible by $p$. I don't understand why comparing coefficients would give us the answer here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not that it's really helpful, but \nmid looks better than \not\vert or \not{|} if you want a symbol for "Does not divide".

Comment: @qaphla- It does look neater, doesn't it. :)

Comment: It works for all $a$ and $b$. Don't plug in numbers, but regard the congruence in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[a,b]$.

Comment: Get rid of those spaces after \nmid

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you calculate the coefficient of $a^{p^n(k-1)}b^{p^n}$ in two ways and compare the results. The equality is only a congruence modulo $p$, so the result we get is also a congruence modulo $p$.

**The first way:**
$$(a+b)^{p^nk}=\sum_{i=0}^{p^nk}{p^nk\choose i}a^{p^nk-i}b^i.$$
To get a term $a^{p^n(k-1)}b^{p^n}$ we must select $i=p^n.$ Thus we get that
$$
(a+b)^{p^nk}=\cdots+{p^nk\choose p^n}a^{p^n(k-1)}b^{p^n}+\cdots.
$$

**The second way:**
Here we calculate (after that application of Freshman's dream)
$(a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^k$. Again using the binomial theorem. This time we get
$$
(a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^k=\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}a^{p^n(k-i)}b^{p^ni}.
$$
To get the desired term we must select $i=1$. Thus
$$
(a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^k=\cdots+{k\choose 1}a^{p^n(k-1)}b^{p^n}+\cdots.
$$
We are working in an algebraic structure (to be more precise: the ring of polynomials in two unknowns $a,b$, with coefficients in the residue class ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$), where the presentation of a polynomial in terms of the basis of monomials is unique. Therefore we can conclude that in the ring
$\mathbb{Z}_p$ we have
$$
{p^nk\choose p^n}={k\choose 1},
$$
or, writing the same thing as a congruence, the claim
$$
{p^nk\choose p^n}\equiv k\pmod p.
$$

Comment: The condition $p\nmid k$ was not necessary. The claim holds always. It follows immediately from Lucas' theorem. Actually the proof is a simplified version of [a proof of Lucas' result](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/82338/11619).

Comment: Thanks for catching the typos, @Daniel. Much appreciated!

Comment: I think this would be easier on the eyes when setting $a=1$ and $b=X$.