# Largest prime no. by which $\left(\binom{60}{30}-1\right)$ is divisible, is

Tags: number-theory

[1] :: Largest prime no. by which $\displaystyle \left(\binom{60}{30}-1\right)$ is divisible, is

[2]:: Calculation of remainder when $\displaystyle \binom{2013}{101}$ is divided by $101$

$\bf{My\; Try}$ for (1):: Using $\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2^n\cdot (1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-1))}{n!}$

So Put $n=30$, we get $\displaystyle \binom{60}{30} = \frac{2^{30}\cdot (1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot 27\cdot 29)}{30!}$

Now I did not understand how can i solve it

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+%2860+choose+30%29-1) I get that ${60\choose 30}-1=3\times 61\times 646254544070281$.  I have no idea how one might get this without serious computation.

Comment: Knowing the prime divisors of $N$ does little for getting the prime divisors of $N-1$ (except for discarding a few primes).

Comment: b.t.w. $$\binom{60}{30}=\frac{2^{30}\cdot(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots57\cdot59)}{30!}$$.

Comment: It is easy to see that if $n$ is even and $2n+1=p$ is a prime, then ${2n\choose n}-1$ is divisible by $2n+1$. That explains the factor $61$ observed by Vadim.

Answer (score 2):

The first question looks prohibitively difficult. Because $101$ is a prime the second question OTOH is a straightforward application of Lucas' correspondence. See [my earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82338/11619) for an on-site proof. Here the numbers in base $101$ are
$$2013=19\cdot101+94,\quad 101=1\cdot101+0,$$
so Lucas tells us that
$$
{2013\choose 101}\equiv{19\choose1}{94\choose 0}=19\cdot1=19\pmod{101}.
$$