# Given integers $a \ge b > 0$ and a prime number $p$, prove that ${pa \choose pb} \equiv {a \choose b} \mod p$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I've been grappling with this problem for a while but haven't solved it.

Given integers $a \ge b > 0$ and a prime number $p$, prove that ${pa \choose pb} \equiv {a \choose b} \mod p$.

Comment: NP. I think this can be solved just using the definition

Comment: You may be interested in the Proof section in the [Wikipedia article on Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem).

Comment: In fact $\displaystyle\binom{pa}{pb}\equiv\binom{a}{b}\pmod{p^3}$

Comment: @Grobber $\binom{2\cdot 3}{2 \cdot 1} = \binom{6}{2} = 15$ and $\binom{3}{1} = 3$, but $15 \not\equiv 3 \bmod 8$.

Comment: J.E. Pin, I am afraid that I had forgotten to mention the above holds for $p\ge 5$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(1+x)^{pa}= \sum_{n=0}^{pa} {pa \choose n} x^{n}$$

\begin{align}
(1+x)^{pa}=\left ((1+x)^{p} \right )^a=\left (\sum_{k=0}^{p}{p \choose k}x^{k} \right )^{a} \Rightarrow\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(1+x)^{pa}&\equiv\left (\sum_{k=0}^{p}{p \choose k}x^{k} \right )^{a} \mod p\\
&\equiv(1+x^p)^{a} \mod p\\
&\equiv \sum_{i=0}^{a} {a \choose i}x^{pi} \mod p
\end{align}

Equating coefficients $\mod p$ it yields $$  {  pa \choose pb} \equiv {a\choose b} \mod p$$

Comment: While reading your proof I think I came up with a variant...or maybe this is the same as your proof: Suppose I use the identity $(a+b+c+...)^p \equiv (a^p+b^p+c^p+...) \mod p$ to show that $((1+x)^a)^p = (\sum {a \choose b}x^b)^p \equiv \sum {a \choose b}^px^{pb}$. Then since $(1+x)^{pa} = \sum {pa \choose k}x^k$ by comparing coefficients we get ${a \choose b}^p \equiv {pa \choose pb} \mod p$, so by Fermat's Little Theorem ${a \choose b} \equiv {pa \choose pb} \mod p$ since $p$ is prime. Is this the same as your proof? (Sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: Fixed a few typos in the second to last displayed line.  Please check.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was indeed the same proof.

Comment: lovely proof!!!

Comment: Haha it says $x^{pi}$. At first I thought it meant $x^{\pi}$

Comment: @Ted Could you please explain in this proof why the coefficients can be equated? I believe that you are correct but do not see why. Relevant question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538321/equating-coefficients-of-binomial-expansion-modulo-p

Answer (score 15):

The following is a combinatorial argument.

Draw $a$ concentric circles and divide them radially into $p$ parts each.  There are then a total of $pa$ regions.  There are $\binom{pa}{pb}$ ways to select $pb$ of these regions.  Consider the action of rotation by $2\pi/p$ on these selections.  There are $\binom{a}{b}$ selections which are fixed by the rotation: these are the selections that consist of $b$ complete annuli.  All others fall into orbits of size $p$.  The desired conclusion $$\binom{pa}{pb} \equiv \binom{a}{b}\, (\text{mod}\,p)$$ 
follows.

Comment: Nice proof! You can easily extend this to $p^2$ by rotating each block individually and considering the equivalence classes formed, which have order $p^n$ where $n$ is the number of partially filled annuli. At least two annuli are partially filled for every valid coloring, so $n\ge 2$ and $p^2$ divides the expression desired.

Comment: [An older related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/82336/11619).