# For p prime, show ${pn \choose pj} \equiv {n \choose j}$ (mod p) for any j = 0, 1, ..., n by considering $(1 + x^p)^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, finite-fields

This is a homework question I've been stuck on for the better chunk of a day, and I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious.

So far I've used the fact that in a finite field with characteristic p, we have that

$(1 + x^p)^n \equiv ((1 + x)^p)^n \equiv (1 + x)^{np} \space \text{(mod p)}$

and that when the left and right ends of this equivalence are expanded via the binomial theorem, I get

$(1 + x^p)^n = {n \choose 0}x^{0} + {n \choose 1}x^{p} + {n \choose 2}x^{2p} + {...} + {n \choose n}x^{np}$

$(1 + x)^{np} = {np \choose 0}x^0 + {np \choose 1}x^1 + {np \choose 2}x^2 + {...} + {np \choose np}x^{np}$

But here is where I'm stuck.  By looking at the terms for both of these expressions, I can see that in order for the problem statement to be true, then we require

${np \choose k} = 0$

whenever k isn't a multiple of p.  And I've read and understand the proof for

${p \choose k} \equiv 0$ (mod p)

which relies on the facts that k < p and p is prime.  But here k need not be less than p, and np is definitely not prime.  So I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof at this point.

*Edit: My confusion is on showing that the terms ${np \choose k}$ are all zero whenever k isn't a multiple of p, or at least their sum is.  The argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538321/equating-coefficients-of-binomial-expansion-modulo-p) is that they all must be 0 because we already know that the two sums are congruent mod p, but that seems kind of circular to me?  If they're congruent, does each coefficient with a k which isn't a multiple of p have to be exactly 0, or would it be better to say their sum is 0 (i.e. all zero implies sum zero, but sum zero doesn't necessarily imply all zero).  Is it because by definition the binomial coefficient is a non-negative integer and thus a sum of non-negative integers summing to zero implies each one must itself be zero?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Nitpick: The polynomial identity $(1+x)^p=1+x^p$ does not hold in a finite field, but rather in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. The formula (aka Freshman's dream) $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ holds in any commutative ring of characteristic $p$. Commutativity is needed because without it we don't have the binomial formula.

Comment: Ah ok.  But isn't $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ a polynomial ring, with 1 and x being elements of the ring, meaning the congruence still holds?

Comment: Absolutely. The proofs in the other threads rely on that identity. But it would not hold, for example, for *all* square matrices over $\Bbb{Z}_p$. It needs $ab=ba$, so if one of $a,b$ is equal to $1$, it still holds.