# Number Theory Proof for $\binom{pA}{pB} \equiv \binom{A}{B} \pmod{p^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I was doing some reading on Wolstenholme's theorem, which states that for prime $p$,
$\binom{pA}{pB} \equiv \binom{A}{B} \pmod{p^3}$ for $p\geq 5$. The proof of the statement is outside my scope, but I was considering why it is still true for $\pmod p$ and $\pmod {p^2}$.

In [Given integers $a \ge b > 0$ and a prime number $p$, prove that ${pa \choose pb} \equiv {a \choose b} \mod p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652886/given-integers-a-ge-b-0-and-a-prime-number-p-prove-that-pa-choose-pb/652917), a fairly straightforward argument is given for the case of $\pmod p$, where they find 2 equivalent expressions and equate them.

I was wondering how I could prove this in similar spirit for the case of $\pmod {p^2}$, without bringing in many additional lemmas, etc.

Comment: Wikipedia has a one-paragraph proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem#A_proof_of_the_theorem

Comment: Thanks Slade, but I am looking for a more elementary NT way to prove it as I am not familiar with group theory. The solution in wikipedia is similar to the second solution in the linked question, which is not what my focus is.

Comment: It's just counting orbits so there really isn't any group theory being used here.  I'll elaborate in an answer when time allows.

Comment: Just give common denominator and bash everything

Answer (score 1):

This is identical to the proof given on Wikipedia, but I've stripped out the group theory in the hopes that will make it more accessible.

Take $a$ boxes and fill each one with the integers modulo $p$, and let $S$ be the resulting set of size $pa$.

Let $T$ be a subset of $S$ of size $pb$, noting that the set of all such $T$ has size ${pa}\choose {pb}$.  Define the "box number" of $T$ to be the number of boxes such that $T$ contains some number in that box, but not all numbers in that box.

We can show without much trouble that the number of subsets with box number $k$ is divisible by $p^k$.  Indeed, every set $T$ with box number $k$ has exactly $p^k$ distinct "rotations" given by adding arbitrary integers mod $p$ to the incomplete boxes.  Here we really need to use the fact that $p$ is prime to see that all these rotations are distinct; this is a nice number theory exercise.

How many subsets $T$ have box number $0$?  Well, for each box, we either pick the whole box or none of the box, and we need to end up with exactly $pb$ elements, so the answer is ${a}\choose{b}$.

To show the final result we want, all we have to do is show that there is no subset with box number $1$, as then we will have written ${pa}\choose{pb}$ as a sum of ${a}\choose{b}$ and something divisible by $p^2$.

But a subset with box number $1$ would be the union of a bunch of complete boxes (with size divisible by $p$), and a single incomplete box (with size not divisible by $p$), so such a subset could not possibly have size $pb$.