# Sums involving binomial coefficients in a finite field

Tags: binomial-coefficients, finite-fields

Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q=p^k$ for some prime $p$. I have some identities related to binomial coefficients over such a field, which I wish to prove. So, can someone tell me a source where I could read up on these?

An example of the identities that I am looking out for is the following. For some $a$, such that $0 \leq a < q$,
$${q(q-1)\choose(q-a)(q-1)} + {(q-1)(q-1)\choose(q-a)(q-1)} + {(q-2)(q-1)\choose(q-a)(q-1)} + . . . + {(q-a)(q-1)\choose(q-a)(q-1)} = 1$$

in $\mathbb{F}_q$. I have some more similar identities that I wish to prove and I would like it if someone could give me a hint / a strategy / a reference for the same. (Please comment if you wish to see more context)

Comment: What's the role of the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ here? It seems to me that $a$ is just an integer, so you are just looking at binomial coefficients modulo $p$. That is, in the field $\Bbb{F}_p$. In that case you may benefit from studying [Lucas Correspondence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasCorrespondenceTheorem.html). For an on-site proof of the identity see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/82338/11619) (Sorry about linking to my own answer. It is just the one I could find fast).

Comment: Yeah, there's no role of $\mathbb{F}_q$ doesn't have any role here. It plays a role in the original problem that I am working on (not mentioned here)

Comment: Makes sense :-) And I'm having second thoughts about Lucas... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the above problem. A general term of the above sum looks like ${(q-t)(q-1) \choose (q-a)(q-1)}$ which is the coefficient of $x^{(q-a)(q-1)}$ in $(1+x)^{(q-t)(q-1)}$. Hence, the sum is the coefficient of $x^{(q-a)(q-1)}$ in $(1+x)^{q(q-1)}+(1+x)^{(q-1)^2}+...+(1+x)^{(q-a)(q-1)}$. We can continue this sum up till 1 as none of those terms will alter any coefficient of $x^{(q-a)(q-1)}$. So, we are looking for the coefficient of $x^{(q-a)(q-1)}$ in:

$$(1+x)^{q(q-1)}+(1+x)^{(q-1)^2}+...+(1+x)^{(q-a)(q-1)} + (1+x)^{(q-a-1)(q-1)} + . . . + 1$$
$$=\frac{(1+x)^{(q-1)(q+1)}-1}{(1+x)^{q-1}-1}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{(1+x)^{q^2}}{1+x}-1}{\frac{(1+x)^q}{1+x}-1}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1+x^{q^2}}{1+x}-1}{\frac{1+x^q}{1+x}-1}$$
$$=\frac{x^{q^2}-x}{x^q-x}$$
$$=\frac{x^{q^2-1}-1}{x^{q-1}-1}$$
$$=1+x^{q-1}+x^{2(q-1)}+...+x^{q(q-1)}$$

And hence, the required coefficient is $1$.